# Checking my understanding of the division algorithm in a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, proof-explanation

This post concerns Proposition 8.15 on page 76 of *Analysis I* by Amann and Escher.

**Text:**

> [image]

**My understanding of how to apply the algorithm:**

Assume $\deg (p) \geq \deg (q)$. If we set $s_{(1)} := p_n q_m^{-1}X^{n - m}$ and $p_{(1)} :=p - s_{(1)}q$, then because of the way the multiplication (convolution) is defined, the leading term of $s_{(1)}q$ will be $p_n X^n$, which is exactly the same as the leading term of $p$ and therefore the subtraction will ensure that $\deg (p_{(1)}) < \deg (p)$.

If $\deg (p_{(1)}) \geq \deg (q)$, then we attempt to divide $p_{(1)}$ by $q$ in a similar manner. Explicitly, say $p_{(1)} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n - j} p_{(1), k} X^k$, where $j > 0$ represents how many steps back we have to take until we find the next non-zero coefficient in the polynomial $p_{(1)}$, and $p_{(1), k}$ is naturally the $k$th coefficient of $p_{(1)}$.

Define $s_{(2)} := p_{(1), n - j}q_m^{-1}X^{n - j - m}$ and $p_{(2)} := p_{(1)} - s_{(2)}q$. Just like before, the leading term of $s_{(2)}q$ will be $p_{(1), n - j}X^{n - j}$ and the subtraction will ensure that $\deg (p_{(2)}) < \deg (p_{(1)})$.

If it were now true that $\deg (p_{(2)}) < \deg (q)$, then we have successfully divided $p_{(1)}$ by $q$, resulting in the equation $p_{(1)} = s_{(2)}q + p_{(2)}$. This can be verified by substituting the definition of $p_{(2)}$.

Successful division of $p_{(1)}$ by $q$ implies successful division of $p$ by $q$. To see this, note that $p_{(1)} = p - s_{(1)}q = s_{(2)}q + p_{(2)}$ and rearrange to get $p = (s_{(1)} + s_{(2)})q + p_{(2)}$, which satisfies (8.23).

Picking up on the pattern, say it took $n$ steps to get a successful division, meaning that $\deg (p_{(n)}) < \deg (q)$. By that point we would have accumulated the terms

\begin{align*}
s_{(1)} &= p_n q_m^{-1}X^{n - m}\\
s_{(2)} &= p_{(1), n - j}q_m^{-1}X^{n - j - m}\\
&\vdots\\
s_{(n)} &= p_{(n - 1), n - j_{(n - 2)}}q_m^{-1}X^{n - j_{(n - 2)} - m}, \text{ and}\\
p_{(1)} &= p - s_{(1)}q\\
p_{(2)} &= p_{(1)} - s_{(2)}q\\
&\vdots\\
p_{(n)} &= p_{(n - 1)} - s_{(n)}q
\end{align*}

where $j, j_{(1)}, \dots, j_{(n - 2)}$ are an increasing sequence of numbers. The final answer is $p = (s_{(1)} + s_{(2)} + \dots + s_{(n)})q + p_{(n)}$, where the right-hand side can be confirmed to equal $p$ by unwinding $p_{(n)}$ all the way.

**Question:**

In the proof of uniqueness, isn't it possible that $\deg (s_{(1)} - s) + \deg (q) = \deg (q)$? In other words, $\deg (s_{(1)} - s) = 0$? This doesn't affect the correctness of the proof of uniqueness, but I'm not sure the strict inequality in the text is correct.

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: You're right. Probably, it's a typo.

Comment: I do hope you realize that they’re simply describing the process of polynomial division, which is usually taught in high schools.

Comment: @Lubin I don't recall learning polynomial division in high school, so I suppose I'm doing it now.

Comment: Well, there’s a way of organizing it so it is a very transparent procedure.

Comment: @Lubin So the way I did it wasn't good? Where should I find a better way of doing/understanding this? I thought I figured it out.

Comment: No, it was correct. The hand algorithms that are so easy to perform in practice are devilishly difficult to describe on paper.